# How to add counter and sum in plotly express treemap

Tags: plotly

**How to add a counter and a sum for the sectors in plotly treemap?**

Current outcome (no counter, no sum): 
*"Asia", "Africa"*

Ideal outcome (with a COUNT and SUM after the name):
 *"Asia 2 countries, 41MM", "Africa 2 countries, 37MM"*

Haven't found anything in docs and on Stack Overflow.

[image]

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = {'Category':['Asia', 'Asia', 'Africa', 'Africa'],
        'Name':['Country 1', 'Country 2', 'Country 3', 'Country 4'],
        'Amount':[20, 21, 19, 18]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig = px.treemap(df,
                path=['Category','Name'], 
                values='Amount')
fig.update_traces(textinfo='value')

fig.show()
```

Preferably I'd like to know how to do it natively in plotly lib. Workarounds are also helpful though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
parent = fig.data[0]['parents']
child = fig.data[0]['labels']

for i,j in zip(*np.unique(parent, return_counts=True)):
    if i != '':
        #parent[parent == i] = i+' '+str(j) # if you have only a root, uncomment this line
        child[child == i] = i+' '+str(j)
```

[image]

Comment: So there is no native way to do in Plotly? Trying to implement your code, but how to do it when px takes dataframe as an input? Please see updated code

Comment: Even if you use dataframe with px.treemap, you need to set labels and parents arguments. Thus, you can use the same code to add the counter.

Comment: BW, I did not see that you updated the code.

Comment: You have two roots in this case, comment the line. I updated my answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! Last thing: trying to np.sum() with fig.data[0]['values'] so that I have both COUNT & SUM.. 
I think I understand your logic with zip, but something is missing in my try 

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to sum up?

Comment: Let me try again:
Ideal outcome "Asia 2 countries, 41MM", "Africa 2 countries, 37MM".
MM are taken from df['Amount']

Comment: I prefer to create another question with your new requirement but I didn't understand with different updates for your question.